# Mobile detection

Tags: javascript, mobile, user-agent, browser-detection

Is there a way to detect mobile devices using Javascript?  Also, I researched that there are such an XML which contains user-agents that could help to identify the mobile handsets.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's subtly different than the suggested duplicate article. The duplicate article discusses screen resolution and this question is about detecting mobile devices in general.

Comment: How is this not constructive? It might be a duplicate of something (probably a few), but it is definitely constructive.

Comment: the admins seem to have extremely narrow and precise requirements for posting on here.

Answer (score 18):

You probably have a normal site and you want to redirect to a mobile site if certain conditions are met, like the screen is very small, or the content is zoomed out to fit on a large "virtual" screen in a small physical space. So, why not check for those conditions instead of testing a zillion UA strings.

Try something like this:

For the UA to report the screen's physical pixel size, this tag must be present in the html page. *

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Now, just get the size of the screen and redirect if needed. Use a slight delay. **

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if ((screen.width < 480) || (screen.height < 480)) {
    location.replace('/mobile/');
  }
}, 100);
```

That's pretty much it. Since this page already has the viewport tag set up for mobile, you could also do the inverse, show mobile here and redirect to full site if screen is bigger.

Edit: I'm not sure why this question has been closed; as far as I can tell it fits the SO format pretty well. Voted to reopen.

<sup>* Inserting it with javascript doesn't seem to work (someone please correct me if you figure out a way). If it isn't present, the phone will report a virtual screen size that is larger than the actual screen. It also doesn't seem to work in iframes, only top level windows (which makes sense because iframes will need to be scaled the same amount as the outer window, they share the same viewport).</sup>

<sup>** Some mobile browsers keep the viewport size from the last loaded page, so they report a large virtual screen size for a few milliseconds, until they notice the meta tag I guess. I couldn't find an early event to hook this into, please comment if you have a better way of doing this. 50 ms delay worked fine in all my tests, 100 should be mostly safe.</sup>

Comment: Wow, really neat solution.. bit ugly I guess but definitely an interesting way of doing it :) Unfortunately though, with pixel densities getting higher and higher I guess this isn't really the best idea. Pixels aren't that indicative of actual physical size...hmm.

Comment: Pixel densities won't affect it, because most (probably all so far) devices with dense pixels report a smaller number of pixels than they actually contain, and report the pixel density separately.

Answer (score 7):

I have this code from K2F, it is in **PHP**, you will have to convert it to javascript.

Shouldn't be too much of a hassle. Knowing constants (text bits) should help you a lot.

```
/**
 * A simple class used to detect whether page<br>
 * is being viewed from a mobile device or not.
 * @copyright 2010 Covac Software
 * @author Christian Sciberras
 * @version 01/05/2010
 */
class Mobile {
    public static function is_mobile(){
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; // get the user agent value - this should be cleaned to ensure no nefarious input gets executed
        $accept     = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; // get the content accept value - this should be cleaned to ensure no nefarious input gets executed
        return false
            || (preg_match('/ipad/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/ipod/i',$user_agent)||preg_match('/iphone/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/android/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/opera mini/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/blackberry/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(pre\/|palm os|palm|hiptop|avantgo|plucker|xiino|blazer|elaine)/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(iris|3g_t|windows ce|opera mobi|windows ce; smartphone;|windows ce; iemobile)/i',$user_agent))
            || (preg_match('/(mini 9.5|vx1000|lge |m800|e860|u940|ux840|compal|wireless| mobi|ahong|lg380|lgku|lgu900|lg210|lg47|lg920|lg840|lg370|sam-r|mg50|s55|g83|t66|vx400|mk99|d615|d763|el370|sl900|mp500|samu3|samu4|vx10|xda_|samu5|samu6|samu7|samu9|a615|b832|m881|s920|n210|s700|c-810|_h797|mob-x|sk16d|848b|mowser|s580|r800|471x|v120|rim8|c500foma:|160x|x160|480x|x640|t503|w839|i250|sprint|w398samr810|m5252|c7100|mt126|x225|s5330|s820|htil-g1|fly v71|s302|-x113|novarra|k610i|-three|8325rc|8352rc|sanyo|vx54|c888|nx250|n120|mtk |c5588|s710|t880|c5005|i;458x|p404i|s210|c5100|teleca|s940|c500|s590|foma|samsu|vx8|vx9|a1000|_mms|myx|a700|gu1100|bc831|e300|ems100|me701|me702m-three|sd588|s800|8325rc|ac831|mw200|brew |d88|htc\/|htc_touch|355x|m50|km100|d736|p-9521|telco|sl74|ktouch|m4u\/|me702|8325rc|kddi|phone|lg |sonyericsson|samsung|240x|x320|vx10|nokia|sony cmd|motorola|up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|vodafone|o2|pocket|kindle|mobile|psp|treo)/i',$user_agent))
            || ((strpos($accept,'text/vnd.wap.wml')>0)||(strpos($accept,'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0))
            || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE'])||isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']))
            || (in_array(strtolower(substr($user_agent,0,4)),array('1207'=>'1207','3gso'=>'3gso','4thp'=>'4thp','501i'=>'501i','502i'=>'502i','503i'=>'503i','504i'=>'504i','505i'=>'505i','506i'=>'506i','6310'=>'6310','6590'=>'6590','770s'=>'770s','802s'=>'802s','a wa'=>'a wa','acer'=>'acer','acs-'=>'acs-','airn'=>'airn','alav'=>'alav','asus'=>'asus','attw'=>'attw','au-m'=>'au-m','aur '=>'aur ','aus '=>'aus ','abac'=>'abac','acoo'=>'acoo','aiko'=>'aiko','alco'=>'alco','alca'=>'alca','amoi'=>'amoi','anex'=>'anex','anny'=>'anny','anyw'=>'anyw','aptu'=>'aptu','arch'=>'arch','argo'=>'argo','bell'=>'bell','bird'=>'bird','bw-n'=>'bw-n','bw-u'=>'bw-u','beck'=>'beck','benq'=>'benq','bilb'=>'bilb','blac'=>'blac','c55/'=>'c55/','cdm-'=>'cdm-','chtm'=>'chtm','capi'=>'capi','cond'=>'cond','craw'=>'craw','dall'=>'dall','dbte'=>'dbte','dc-s'=>'dc-s','dica'=>'dica','ds-d'=>'ds-d','ds12'=>'ds12','dait'=>'dait','devi'=>'devi','dmob'=>'dmob','doco'=>'doco','dopo'=>'dopo','el49'=>'el49','erk0'=>'erk0','esl8'=>'esl8','ez40'=>'ez40','ez60'=>'ez60','ez70'=>'ez70','ezos'=>'ezos','ezze'=>'ezze','elai'=>'elai','emul'=>'emul','eric'=>'eric','ezwa'=>'ezwa','fake'=>'fake','fly-'=>'fly-','fly_'=>'fly_','g-mo'=>'g-mo','g1 u'=>'g1 u','g560'=>'g560','gf-5'=>'gf-5','grun'=>'grun','gene'=>'gene','go.w'=>'go.w','good'=>'good','grad'=>'grad','hcit'=>'hcit','hd-m'=>'hd-m','hd-p'=>'hd-p','hd-t'=>'hd-t','hei-'=>'hei-','hp i'=>'hp i','hpip'=>'hpip','hs-c'=>'hs-c','htc '=>'htc ','htc-'=>'htc-','htca'=>'htca','htcg'=>'htcg','htcp'=>'htcp','htcs'=>'htcs','htct'=>'htct','htc_'=>'htc_','haie'=>'haie','hita'=>'hita','huaw'=>'huaw','hutc'=>'hutc','i-20'=>'i-20','i-go'=>'i-go','i-ma'=>'i-ma','i230'=>'i230','iac'=>'iac','iac-'=>'iac-','iac/'=>'iac/','ig01'=>'ig01','im1k'=>'im1k','inno'=>'inno','iris'=>'iris','jata'=>'jata','java'=>'java','kddi'=>'kddi','kgt'=>'kgt','kgt/'=>'kgt/','kpt '=>'kpt ','kwc-'=>'kwc-','klon'=>'klon','lexi'=>'lexi','lg g'=>'lg g','lg-a'=>'lg-a','lg-b'=>'lg-b','lg-c'=>'lg-c','lg-d'=>'lg-d','lg-f'=>'lg-f','lg-g'=>'lg-g','lg-k'=>'lg-k','lg-l'=>'lg-l','lg-m'=>'lg-m','lg-o'=>'lg-o','lg-p'=>'lg-p','lg-s'=>'lg-s','lg-t'=>'lg-t','lg-u'=>'lg-u','lg-w'=>'lg-w','lg/k'=>'lg/k','lg/l'=>'lg/l','lg/u'=>'lg/u','lg50'=>'lg50','lg54'=>'lg54','lge-'=>'lge-','lge/'=>'lge/','lynx'=>'lynx','leno'=>'leno','m1-w'=>'m1-w','m3ga'=>'m3ga','m50/'=>'m50/','maui'=>'maui','mc01'=>'mc01','mc21'=>'mc21','mcca'=>'mcca','medi'=>'medi','meri'=>'meri','mio8'=>'mio8','mioa'=>'mioa','mo01'=>'mo01','mo02'=>'mo02','mode'=>'mode','modo'=>'modo','mot '=>'mot ','mot-'=>'mot-','mt50'=>'mt50','mtp1'=>'mtp1','mtv '=>'mtv ','mate'=>'mate','maxo'=>'maxo','merc'=>'merc','mits'=>'mits','mobi'=>'mobi','motv'=>'motv','mozz'=>'mozz','n100'=>'n100','n101'=>'n101','n102'=>'n102','n202'=>'n202','n203'=>'n203','n300'=>'n300','n302'=>'n302','n500'=>'n500','n502'=>'n502','n505'=>'n505','n700'=>'n700','n701'=>'n701','n710'=>'n710','nec-'=>'nec-','nem-'=>'nem-','newg'=>'newg','neon'=>'neon','netf'=>'netf','noki'=>'noki','nzph'=>'nzph','o2 x'=>'o2 x','o2-x'=>'o2-x','opwv'=>'opwv','owg1'=>'owg1','opti'=>'opti','oran'=>'oran','p800'=>'p800','pand'=>'pand','pg-1'=>'pg-1','pg-2'=>'pg-2','pg-3'=>'pg-3','pg-6'=>'pg-6','pg-8'=>'pg-8','pg-c'=>'pg-c','pg13'=>'pg13','phil'=>'phil','pn-2'=>'pn-2','pt-g'=>'pt-g','palm'=>'palm','pana'=>'pana','pire'=>'pire','pock'=>'pock','pose'=>'pose','psio'=>'psio','qa-a'=>'qa-a','qc-2'=>'qc-2','qc-3'=>'qc-3','qc-5'=>'qc-5','qc-7'=>'qc-7','qc07'=>'qc07','qc12'=>'qc12','qc21'=>'qc21','qc32'=>'qc32','qc60'=>'qc60','qci-'=>'qci-','qwap'=>'qwap','qtek'=>'qtek','r380'=>'r380','r600'=>'r600','raks'=>'raks','rim9'=>'rim9','rove'=>'rove','s55/'=>'s55/','sage'=>'sage','sams'=>'sams','sc01'=>'sc01','sch-'=>'sch-','scp-'=>'scp-','sdk/'=>'sdk/','se47'=>'se47','sec-'=>'sec-','sec0'=>'sec0','sec1'=>'sec1','semc'=>'semc','sgh-'=>'sgh-','shar'=>'shar','sie-'=>'sie-','sk-0'=>'sk-0','sl45'=>'sl45','slid'=>'slid','smb3'=>'smb3','smt5'=>'smt5','sp01'=>'sp01','sph-'=>'sph-','spv '=>'spv ','spv-'=>'spv-','sy01'=>'sy01','samm'=>'samm','sany'=>'sany','sava'=>'sava','scoo'=>'scoo','send'=>'send','siem'=>'siem','smar'=>'smar','smit'=>'smit','soft'=>'soft','sony'=>'sony','t-mo'=>'t-mo','t218'=>'t218','t250'=>'t250','t600'=>'t600','t610'=>'t610','t618'=>'t618','tcl-'=>'tcl-','tdg-'=>'tdg-','telm'=>'telm','tim-'=>'tim-','ts70'=>'ts70','tsm-'=>'tsm-','tsm3'=>'tsm3','tsm5'=>'tsm5','tx-9'=>'tx-9','tagt'=>'tagt','talk'=>'talk','teli'=>'teli','topl'=>'topl','hiba'=>'hiba','up.b'=>'up.b','upg1'=>'upg1','utst'=>'utst','v400'=>'v400','v750'=>'v750','veri'=>'veri','vk-v'=>'vk-v','vk40'=>'vk40','vk50'=>'vk50','vk52'=>'vk52','vk53'=>'vk53','vm40'=>'vm40','vx98'=>'vx98','virg'=>'virg','vite'=>'vite','voda'=>'voda','vulc'=>'vulc','w3c '=>'w3c ','w3c-'=>'w3c-','wapj'=>'wapj','wapp'=>'wapp','wapu'=>'wapu','wapm'=>'wapm','wig '=>'wig ','wapi'=>'wapi','wapr'=>'wapr','wapv'=>'wapv','wapy'=>'wapy','wapa'=>'wapa','waps'=>'waps','wapt'=>'wapt','winc'=>'winc','winw'=>'winw','wonu'=>'wonu','x700'=>'x700','xda2'=>'xda2','xdag'=>'xdag','yas-'=>'yas-','your'=>'your','zte-'=>'zte-','zeto'=>'zeto','acs-'=>'acs-','alav'=>'alav','alca'=>'alca','amoi'=>'amoi','aste'=>'aste','audi'=>'audi','avan'=>'avan','benq'=>'benq','bird'=>'bird','blac'=>'blac','blaz'=>'blaz','brew'=>'brew','brvw'=>'brvw','bumb'=>'bumb','ccwa'=>'ccwa','cell'=>'cell','cldc'=>'cldc','cmd-'=>'cmd-','dang'=>'dang','doco'=>'doco','eml2'=>'eml2','eric'=>'eric','fetc'=>'fetc','hipt'=>'hipt','http'=>'http','ibro'=>'ibro','idea'=>'idea','ikom'=>'ikom','inno'=>'inno','ipaq'=>'ipaq','jbro'=>'jbro','jemu'=>'jemu','java'=>'java','jigs'=>'jigs','kddi'=>'kddi','keji'=>'keji','kyoc'=>'kyoc','kyok'=>'kyok','leno'=>'leno','lg-c'=>'lg-c','lg-d'=>'lg-d','lg-g'=>'lg-g','lge-'=>'lge-','libw'=>'libw','m-cr'=>'m-cr','maui'=>'maui','maxo'=>'maxo','midp'=>'midp','mits'=>'mits','mmef'=>'mmef','mobi'=>'mobi','mot-'=>'mot-','moto'=>'moto','mwbp'=>'mwbp','mywa'=>'mywa','nec-'=>'nec-','newt'=>'newt','nok6'=>'nok6','noki'=>'noki','o2im'=>'o2im','opwv'=>'opwv','palm'=>'palm','pana'=>'pana','pant'=>'pant','pdxg'=>'pdxg','phil'=>'phil','play'=>'play','pluc'=>'pluc','port'=>'port','prox'=>'prox','qtek'=>'qtek','qwap'=>'qwap','rozo'=>'rozo','sage'=>'sage','sama'=>'sama','sams'=>'sams','sany'=>'sany','sch-'=>'sch-','sec-'=>'sec-','send'=>'send','seri'=>'seri','sgh-'=>'sgh-','shar'=>'shar','sie-'=>'sie-','siem'=>'siem','smal'=>'smal','smar'=>'smar','sony'=>'sony','sph-'=>'sph-','symb'=>'symb','t-mo'=>'t-mo','teli'=>'teli','tim-'=>'tim-','tosh'=>'tosh','treo'=>'treo','tsm-'=>'tsm-','upg1'=>'upg1','upsi'=>'upsi','vk-v'=>'vk-v','voda'=>'voda','vx52'=>'vx52','vx53'=>'vx53','vx60'=>'vx60','vx61'=>'vx61','vx70'=>'vx70','vx80'=>'vx80','vx81'=>'vx81','vx83'=>'vx83','vx85'=>'vx85','wap-'=>'wap-','wapa'=>'wapa','wapi'=>'wapi','wapp'=>'wapp','wapr'=>'wapr','webc'=>'webc','whit'=>'whit','winw'=>'winw','wmlb'=>'wmlb','xda-'=>'xda-',)))
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the link to this source?

Comment: @Phill Pafford - Unfortunately, K2F is not publicly available yet.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a JS script called "**redirection_mobile.js**" to solve this issue. It detects the User Agent and redirects to a mobile version if you're accessing a site from a mobile device.

In some case you want to redirect from a mobile device to a desktop version (like with a link "Go to the main site"), the script will handle that and once you finish your session, you'll access to the mobile version again.

You can find the source code on github here **https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site** and you can read more details in one of my articles here:

http://blog.sebarmeli.com/2010/11/02/how-to-redirect-your-site-to-a-mobile-version-through-javascript/

Comment: I appreciate all the folks warning against browser sniffing, but capability detection doesn't work well when you just want to send mobile devices to a site that is optimized for them.  We have squid in front of our application server, and needed a javascript solution that was free--this one fit the bill.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The very last place I recommend browser sniffing code is mobile. It's the wild west out there right now and nobody is reading from the same rule book. I've heard rumors some browsers are mimicking other user agents to avoid sniffing code that excludes them just like IE used to back in the '90s.

Test by method and google progressive enhancement if you don't already know what it means. Some browser implementations of JS are so messed up they're not worth trying to accomodate and should be served versions of a site that work without JS, IMO.

Just look at what JQuery's core team considers C-grade (not worth supporting) on their graded compatibility tables. And yes, I believe this applies to both the core and the JQ mobile library (which is kind of like JQ ui for mobile, not JQ core for mobile - still needs core to work).

http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using Javascript to detect mobile devices for the simple reason that many of them do not support Javascript, so your detection code is not guaranteed to work on all devices.

Usually the detection is done server-side using a descriptor file like [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) which will not only help you detect the various mobile user-agents, but also their capabilities, screen sizes, color depths, etc. That way you can serve up a different configuration of assets (javascript files, image sizes, etc.) depending on the mobile device.

Comment: Agreed. I browse on my BlackBerry with JS disabled, and I doubt I'm alone in that.

Comment: -1 It could have been that all the world disabled JS on mobile phones, but the OP never asked THAT.

Comment: He also didn't ask how to set his head on fire but I wouldn't recommend that either. Browser sniffing as a universal means of detection for writing cross-browser code is a lousy idea for regular browsers, but a spectacularly horrible one for mobile.

Comment: -1, JavaScript disabled? 2 years ago: yes. Now: no.

Comment: @Derek he wrote it over two years ago, sort of unfair to downvote after the fact ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have published the last version of "Apache Mobile Filter", this open source project has in the first 8 months, more than 1100 downloads from sourceforge and I suppose the same from CPAN.

The Apache Mobile Filter allows you to access WURFL from any programming language, not just Java and php that is traditionally used for dynamic mobile web sites.

The module detects the mobile device and passes the WURFL capabilities on to the other web application as environment variables. It can also be used to resize images on the fly to adapt to the screen size of the mobile device.

Try it and let me know your opinion.

For more info: http://www.idelfuschini.it/it/apache-mobile-filter-v2x.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.hand-interactive.com/resources/detect-mobile-javascript.htm

```
var deviceBB = "blackberry";

//Initialize our user agent string to lower case. 
var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

//************************** // Detects if the current browser is a BlackBerry of some sort. 

function DetectBlackBerry() {    
if (uagent.search(deviceBB) > -1)
      return true;    else
      return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Plug in [Handset Detection](http://www.handsetdetection.com). You can use Javascript, PHP or most popular scripting languages. We deal with the pain so you don't have to :-) Disclaimer - i work there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a mobile detection Javascript which I can guarantee to work very well even with thin clients like Opera MIni (disclaimer: I wrote it):

https://github.com/miohtama/detectmobile.js