# HTML / CSS Ad position fixing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need 2 ad containers to be displayed next to my website body (right hand side), but the ads should be displayed only if I am in a desktop / screen size = wider than my website container width. This website is mainly for mobile & I don't need the ads to be displayed in mobile, because we cannot accomodate this ads in mobile screen.

Given my html code below;

```
<div style="width:320px; height:500px; background-color:#C60; margin:0 auto;">Website</div>
<div id="ad-contextual" style="width:222px; height:150px; float:left; margin-right:20px; background-color:#39F;">Contextual Ads</div>
<div id="ad-sky" style="width:222px; height:600px; float:left; background-color:#996;">Skyscrapers Ads</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'd say "use a CSS3 Media Query", but in this case hiding the box is not good enough - you'd be generating fraudulent views that way, especially if the site is mainly for mobile devices.

Instead, use JavaScript to detect `if( screen.width > 800)` (adjust the number as needed) and only insert the ad if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the browser and operating system by sniffing user agent. Then you may deliver the ad by setting a conditional statement in JavaSript. If the platform id Desktop, then show ad, else, hide ad.

refer this stackoverflow question [Mobile detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743129/mobile-detection-using-javascript)

and this one also [Auto detect mobile browser (via user-agent?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent)

Also search Google for more options.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to do this:

First using jQuery:

```
var pagewidth = $(window).width();
if (pagewidth > 320) {      
    $("#ad-contextual").css("display", "block");
    $("#ad-sky").css("display", "block");

}
else { 
    $("#ad-contextual").css("display", "none");
    $("#ad-sky").css("display", "none");
}
```

Second using CSS Media Query:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
     #ad-contextual { display:none; }
     #ad-sky { display:none; }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
     #ad-contextual { display:none; }
     #ad-sky { display:none; }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
     #ad-contextual { display:none; }
     #ad-sky { display:none; }
}
```