# Can I use javascript to detect a mobile device and restrict access to a normal browser?

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile, browser

I want my web page to detect whether the user is using a handheld device and if so allow access to mobile site and if not redirect to main site. I am assuming this would be done in JavaScript. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction.

EDIT

I would still like to use javascript as it is the language I have used throughout the project.

SOLVED

```
<script language="javascript"> 

 var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
          if (mobile) {
              window.location.replace("http://scmweb.infj.
              ulst.ac.uk/~b00519427/finalwebsite/homepage.html");
          }
          else
            window.location.replace("http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/");

   </script>
```

SOLVED

Comment: You should checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser

Comment: Does scope of "handheld device" include all the possible handheld devices that are available? You can get close by following these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery

Comment: Understand that this is a dangerous practice, because you may end up blocking devices that are perfectly capable of using your site. For example, not all Android devices are "mobile devices" -- Android can run on laptops, set-top boxes, etc.

Comment: what would you suggest. BAring in mind i want to keep it extremly simple @apsillers

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743129/mobile-detection-using-javascript

Comment: I would suggest deciding for yourself what constitutes a "mobile device" (small screen size? touch support? low graphics performance?) and use feature detection to test for those properties on each device (for example, by using [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

To really enforce a particular site, JS is not the right choice since it can easily be disabled. Hence, I would propose a server side decision and enforcement. For this, you can use  a .htaccess file and the USER_AGENT rule, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess).